# Erlang - pattern match ext_binary(), result from term_to_binary()

Tags: erlang

G'day Erlangers!

I want to pattern match and differentiate between a result of term_to_binary() and a regular binary string, e.g. <<"hello :))">>.

The result of term_to_binary() is a string with the type of ext_binary() but I'm not sure how to pattern-match this, without pattern matching regular binary strings.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If `term_to_binary()` is called in current Erlang version, it'll start with the `131` byte, as shown in http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_ext_dist.html. It doesn't say what previous version numbers were (e.g. before maps were added), but I suspect 128 to 130.
2. `131` is [not a printable character in Latin1](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/character_set.html), nor a legal starting byte in UTF-8.

So `<<131, _/binary>>` should match only current ETF-encoded terms.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot Alexey!